# Error E3841 Unable to find session number in Arcserve

Tags: backup

When trying to restore data or performing a scan, I get the following error:

`E3841 Unable to find session number, EC=Error session active`

In the log file I see the following line:

```
[12/20 10:38:38 0ce8  1 TK        3472   6] FSD: FSD_ClientGotoSession(): Open session file failed JobID[3472] DeviceNumber[8] Session[1] MS=5
```

Backups are stored on a NAS, accessed by Windows share.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by wrong ACL settings on the NAS. It was the *MS=5* part of the error message that guided me in that direction because error 5 is mostly security/ACL related.